# Is it possible to show the Wireshark Color Rule name as a Column?

Tags: wireshark

I have set up some color rules matching some filters, and would like to see the name of the filter in the Wireshark window alongside each capture possibly to the left of the Time column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark exposes the coloring rule name in the [frame.coloring_rule.name](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html) display filter field. There are a couple of ways to add it as a column:

- Expand the "Frame" packet detail item. Right click on "Coloring Rule Name" and select "[Apply as Column](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDisplayPopUpSection.html#ChWorkPacketDetailsPanePopUpMenuSection)".
- Go to "Preferences → Columns". Create a new column. Set its type to "Custom" and set the field value to "frame.coloring_rule.name".